# Drupal Date Repeat Module has no delete option

Tags: datetime

I'm using a custom content type with the drupal date field inserted with the date-popup calendar.  The content type allows for multiple dates however there is no delete option, so they just keep piling up.  The content type is used to run the event module I created.  Any ideas?

Comment: Leave the fields that you want to empty blank, then save the form

Comment: @Clive with things like date popup in place it might be impossible.

Comment: @Mołot How so? A JS widget shouldn't be interfering with form validation, if it is I'd class that as a bug

Comment: @Clive [inline datepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker) can replace text box, making it impossible to blank it. It is a basic incompatibility where two things works as advertised, but together fail miserably. Is it a bug? Hard to tell, I don't even know if that's what OP encountered. I just seen it happen (with my own custom widget, to be honest).

Comment: @Mołot If that module completely replaces the input with a div, and doesn't maintain an input with the same name in the background which contains the _real_ data, then it can't possibly work. Form submission would fail every time. So we're back in bug territory I'd say

Comment: @Clive *if* my *guess* about what OP is using is right, then yes. Now for me it's more of an "unclear what you're asking" case, but I will not argue about it.

Comment: I can remove the date but not the time - surprising how the date module doesn't have a delete option - pretty widely used.

Comment: Update: Saving as blank will not remove the current date. Could anyone assist in hooking into this content type so I can add the option myself?

Comment: @user3421538 Saving a field as blank _will_ remove the data, so something must be interfering and re-adding the data back in. Have you checked the date module issue queue? It sounds like an odd thing to be missing.